# FFmpeg does not always fully concat video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concat two video clips, sometimes i end up with only three fourths of the video, sometimes I only get one half, and sometimes i manage to get the whole thing. Anyone ever deal with this? Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:videos/clip1.ts|videos/clip2.ts"  -ar 44100  -b:a 128k -b:v 800k -vcodeclibx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 120 videos/output.ts
```

I just dont understand why sometimes it works perfectly and other times i only get part of the video.

Comment: Sorry, but this has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy and you needn't ffmpeg to concat videos. Our videos: video1.mp4, video2.mp4

```
cat video* > full_video.mp4
```

Another option, create a playlist, (a text file containing the names of the videos)

Create *Playlist.txt* or *playlist.m3u8*  and add in to this file put the path of videos:

> video1.mp4
>
> video2.mp4

and the call to ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg - i playlist.txt - codec .... fullvideo.ts
```